# How this set of formulas are satisfiable?

Tags: logic, model-theory, first-order-logic

> David Marker's Model Theory:
>   **Theorem 4.2.11**   Suppose that $T$ is a complete theory in a countable language and $A \subseteq M \models T$ is countable. If $|S_n^M(A)| < 2^{\aleph_{0}}$, then $|S_n^M(A)| < {\aleph_{0}}$.
>   **Proof.**  Suppose that $|S_n^M(A)| > {\aleph_{0}}$. We claim that $|S_n^M(A)| = 2^{\aleph_{0}}$ . Because $|S_n^M(A)| > {\aleph_{0}}$ and there are only countably many $L_A$-formulas, there is a formula $\phi$ such that $|[\phi]| > {\aleph_{0}}$.
>   **Claim**   If $|[\phi]| > {\aleph_{0}}$, there is an $L_A$-formula $\psi$ such that $|[\phi \wedge \psi]| > {\aleph_{0}}$ and $|[\phi \wedge \neg\psi]| > {\aleph_{0}}$.
>   Suppose not. Let $p =   \big\{\psi(\bar{v}):|[\phi \wedge \psi]| > {\aleph_{0}}\big\} $. Clearly, for each $\psi$ either $\psi \in p$ or $\neg \psi \in p$ but not both. We claim that $p$ is satisfiable. Suppose that $\psi_1,...,\psi_m \in p$. Either $\psi_1\wedge...\wedge\psi_m \in p$, in which case $\big\{\psi_1,...,\psi_m \big\}  ∪ Th_A(M)$ is satisfiable, or $\neg\psi_1 ∨ . . . ∨ \neg\psi_m \in p$. Because $[\neg\psi_1 ∨ . . . ∨ \neg\psi_m]=[\neg\psi_1]∪...∪[\neg\psi_m]$,
>   we must have $|[\neg\psi_i]| > {\aleph_{0}}$ for some $1\leq i\leq m$, a contradiction. Thus $p \in S_n^M(A)$.

My question is about this part of the proof which says if $\psi_1\wedge...\wedge\psi_m \in p$ then $\big\{\psi_1,...,\psi_m \big\}  ∪ Th_A(M)$ is satisfiable!
I can't see why that's true. Would be thankful for your help.

Comment: Does "$[\chi]$" mean "the number of models of $T\cup\{\chi\}$"? If not, what does it mean?

Comment: @NoahSchweber It means the set of all types containing $\chi$. It's Marker's notation for the basic clopens in the Stone space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\psi_1\land \ldots\land \psi_m\in p$, then by definition $|[\psi_1\land \ldots\land \psi_m]|>\aleph_0$. In particular, this set is nonempty. So there's some type $q\in S^M_n(A)$ containing $\psi_1\land\ldots\land \psi_m$. Since types are consistent, $\{\psi_1,\dots,\psi_m\}\cup \mathrm{Th}_A(M)$ is satisfiable.

Comment: Thank you Alex, it was simply beautiful!